# XKCD Web Scraper - Automate the Boring Stuff

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm currently on Chapter 11 of ATBS and working through the Web Scraper project. I can get it to run fine however the web comics are never actually downloaded on my Mac.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

#downloadXkcd.py - Downloads every single XKCD comic.

import requests, os, bs4

url = 'http://xkcd.com'             # starting URL
os.makedirs('xkcd', exist_ok=True)  # store comics in ./xkcd

while not url.endswith('#'):

    #TODO: DL the page
    print('Downloading page %s...' % url)
    res = requests.get(url)
    res.raise_for_status()

    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text)

    #TODO: Find URL of image
    comicElem = soup.select('#comic img')
    if comicElem == []:
        print('Could not find comic image.')
    else:
        comicUrl = 'http:' + comicElem[0].get('src')

        #TODO: Download Image
        print('Downloading image %s' % (comicUrl))
        res = requests.get(comicUrl)
        res.raise_for_status()

        #TODO: Save image to ./xkcd
        imageFile = open(os.path.join('xkcd', os.path.basename(comicUrl)), 'wb')
        for chunk in res.iter_content(100000):
            imageFile.write(chunk)
        imageFile.close()

    #TODO: Get prev button URL
    prevLink = soup.select('a[rel="prev"]')[0]
    url = 'http://xkcd.com' + prevLink.get('href')

print('Done.')
```

What do I need to fix in order to get the comics to download? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to SO! You might want to reformulate your answer so that it is much more specific. Otherwise nobody would know how to help you.

Comment: do you get error message ? Then show full message in question (as text, not image)

Comment: do you see message "Downloading image URL" ? Is there correct URL ? Can you download image using this URL in web browser?  You can use `print()` to see if you have correct values in variables.

Comment: instead of `if comicElem == []:` we rather use `if not comicElem:` or eventually `if len(comicElem) == 0:`

Comment: Try adding `print(os.getcwd())` to the start of your script to display where your images will be saved. Your script does appear to be correctly downloading the images.

Comment: As stated above, your script works fine. It's saving it in the current working directory that you .py file is located. The other option is you can explicitly give the path: ie. change anywhere that you see `'xkcd'` to `'C:/xkcd'`

Answer (score 0):

You seemed to have left out the html.parser as follows:

```
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')
```